# How to replace ::new in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Following a tutorial on Disruptor in Java and they make the following call

```
Disruptor<LongEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<>(LongEvent::new, bufferSize, executor);
```

Where `LongEvent` is instantiated using a default constructor of no argument- ie. `new LongEvent()`.

The equivalent line in Kotlin is throwing an error at the `::new`. What is the correct syntax for `::new` in Kotlin?

```
# THIS IS INVALID
val disruptor = Disruptor<LongEvent>(LongEvent::new, bufferSize, executor)
```

Answer (score 5):

the [constructor reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#constructor-references) in kotlin is `::LongEvent`.

> Constructors can be referenced just like methods and properties. 
>   Constructors are referenced by using the `::` operator and *adding the **class name***.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, didn't know what to search to find that duplicated question.

Comment: @AdamHughes Not at all. you can see more detailed here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#constructor-references